# Scheduling aws lambda function for sending email

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

i can write a lambda function which will send email to a specific user using SES . what i want to do is to make some kind of schedule task which will trigger this lambda function . the lambda function should accept user-email as function parameter as different user have different email and this lambda function should be trigger in different time for different user . how can achieve this ? i already did some digging about SNS, SQS, CloudeWatch, step function and i got confused . can anyone help me here ?

Comment: Where do you maintain these input such as user email to lambda? Because if you would like to schedule lambda, there must be some source from where can get the user email. There are different techniques for scheduling lambda.

Comment: @KaiBurjack i'm talking about 100k users

Comment: @amitd currently we are using mongodb inside our ec2  instance

Comment: @Aninda - Are you looking for execution/trigger of lambda based on any update or insert event into mongodb user specific record . OR lambda must be execute per regular intervals for example say per 15 minutes and each of this scheduled execution of lambda at the most process only one user email.?

Comment: @amitd i don't want execute it in regular intervals basis . i want to give email to the users before their subscription/trial period ended . as different user has different subscription/trial ended date, so need to send the email in different date

Comment: Hi, were you able to design the architecture. I've the same requirements for the client but with 20K users for different timezones. You can connect with me [link]aadeez.13@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AWS tutorial that shows you how to write a Lambda function that uses the Lambda runtime API. This document shows you how to invoke other AWS services from the Lambda function (such as Amazon DynamoDB). In this example, user data is located in a database, not passed to the Lambda function (this is a minor diff from what you described).

The Lambda function is invoked on a regular schedule using scheduled events. This tutorial walks you through all steps.

[Creating scheduled events to invoke Lambda functions](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events)

Answer (score 0):

Following are some of the options;

**Option - 1)**

a) An observer = A lambda to check connect and check in mongodb for list of user's,  for whom subscription/trial period is about to end. Have list of emails and part of message body such as date and other details which will be used in drafting email (in json format with key as email) of such users

b) A command executer = A lambda which will take list of emails and mapped contents. Iterate over this list and send email to the user's from the list

c) [Schedule a Serverless Workflow](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/scheduling-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-cloudwatch-events/) using AWS step functions use/connect lambda a) and b) in this

Additional information: Refer [Error handling in Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html) for negative test cases

**OR**

**Option - 2)** I am not sure whether this is available for the setup of mongodb you have;

a) Using [MongoDB Scheduled Triggers](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/triggers#scheduled-triggers)

b) [MongoDB Scheduled Triggers integrated via. AWS Eventbridge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/ingesting-mongodb-atlas-data-using-amazon-eventbridge/) mapped to AWS Lambda with logic to send email.

**OR**

Option 3) Combine observer (1.a) and command executer (1.b) logic within single lambda. Schedule this lambda as per your requirements using [AWS cloudwatch event rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

Answer (score -1):

Create CloudWatch trigger for each user if you have a small amount of users. Otherwise trigger the function frequently, say, every minutes by CW and save the last time for each user in a dynamo table.